# X Driver for underlying hardware

Tags: linux, xorg

I am following LFS and BLFS. I want to run the resultant filesystem onto many different hardware, with "native" graphics driver.

If the underlying hardware's graphic card is intel then it must start X with `intel` driver.

My question is, how do I find out which Xorg driver is appropriate for underlying graphic card.

e.g. If Intel supports following chipset.

```
i810
i810-dc100
i810e
i815
i830M
845G
854
852GM/855GM
865G
915G
```

and if underlying graphic card is one of them, then I can use Intel to start X. But I have no idea, how do I list out this chipset name before calling X

Comment: install ALL OF THE DRIVERS! Xorg will detect which one is appropriate when it starts.

Comment: That was the first thought came in my mind. But I want to ask user, if he want native driver or Vesa.

Comment: in that case, I would include logic for overriding with Vesa. if the user doesn't want Vesa, start X normally and let it do autodetection.

Comment: What will happen if none of the driver is native ? Will it start with `VESA` on it's own ? Do i have to mention it any Xorg configuration file ?

Comment: yes. if no driver but VESA is available, that is what will be used.

Comment: So what all it means that there is no need to add `device` section in any of xorg config file. Right ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12814/discussion-between-shw-and-strugee)